# Faster way to count smaller or equal element in an very big array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search

I need to reduce the time complexity of my code, so far I tried to presort it and use binary search to find the index of needed element and use the index to find how many elements before the key number, but I can't pass because my code is slow. Is there any other method I can do to make this code faster ?

Important details :

- I need to run this code with a big array and multiple queries (array remain unchanged) , both at most 100k.
- The value of each element is at most 1 billion.
- The time limit for this problem is 0,1s

Example :

Suppose I have an array with 15 elements in it and I have 5 queries to do.

Array : 1002 19 3 8 22 123 14 5234 123 657 41
829 34 2314 15

Queries : 100 1000 78 3 1

Output : 8 12 8 1 0

I tried presorting it and using binary search, but still I can't pass the 0,1s time limit.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void swap(int *a,int *b){
    int temp=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=temp;
}

int partition(int a[],int p,int r){
    int temp, i,x;
    x=a[r];
    i=p-1;
    for(int j=p;j<=r;j++){
        if(a[j]<x){
            i++;
            swap(&a[i],&a[j]);
        }
    }
    i++;
    swap(&a[i],&a[r]);;
    return i;
}

void qsort(int a[],int p,int r){
    int q;
    if(p<r){
        q=partition(a,p,r);
        qsort(a,p,q-1);
        qsort(a,q+1,r);
    }
}

int binarySearch(int arr[], int n, int key){ 
    int left = 0, right = n; 
    int mid; 
    while (left < right){ 
        mid = left + (right-left)/2; 
        if (arr[mid] == key){ 
            while (arr[mid+1] == key && mid+1<n) 
                 mid++; 
            break; 
        }else if (arr[mid] > key) 
            right = mid; 
        else
            left = mid + 1; 
    } 
    while (arr[mid] > key) 
        mid--; 
    return mid + 1; 
} 

int main(){
    int a, b;
    scanf("%d %d",&a, &b);
    int data[a],d;
    for(int i=0;i<a;i++){
        scanf("%d", &data[i]);
    }   
    qsort(c, 0, a-1);
    for(int i=0;i<b;i++){
        scanf("%d", &d);
        printf("%d\n", binarySearch(c, a, d));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use the already defined qsort from stdlib, also if you can use c++ you can use the sort and lower_bound/upper_bound functions to replace qsort and binary search.

Comment: You have a bug here: `while (arr[mid+1] == key && mid+1<n)`. You need to make sure that the index check occurs before the item check. If you access `arr[mid+1]` before you do the bounds check, you could get an access violation.

Comment: Also looks like a bug in `with (arr[mid] > key)`. If `key` is smaller than any item in the array, this looks like `mid` could go negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, could you tell us what is the current execution time on a chosen by you fixed 100k element array for a given iteration list? This will give us an idea of how far you are from the limit.

Second, execution time not only depends on complexity but also each loop execution time. This is why you can have two algorithms with different complexity but having the higher complexity one running faster than the other one just because it is running on a low enough number of elements.
Saying that, in your case, the complexity has a role for sure. Nevertheless the running time of each loop is important, which is implementation dependent. Therefore may I suggest the following:

- Increase the optimisation level of your compiler (-O option)
- Change some of your code. As example `mid = left + (right-left)/2;` could be simplified to `mid = (left + right) >> 1;`. This will be increase your code speed already. (I have edited this part to change the right shift to 1)
- Change your loops check. Transform them to test against `0` instead, your code will be a lot faster.
- Also, each test is going to cost you time so it is better to read and write instead of test to see whether you have to read or write.

## Note:

You could perhaps try another approach where numbers would be organised as a tree according to each digit. As example 12 123 1237 15 24 26 1256 would build a tree like where the last digit would be marked to indicate it is a leaf (end on a number). Of course this tree can also be build from binary values

`1 - 2 - 3 - 7
       - 5 - 6
   - 5
 2 - 4
   - 6`

After that one would only need to travel along the tree and compare the length and value of each digit.

Just an idea though!

Answer (score 1):

In general your approach is right and should provide average time `NlogN + MlogN` where N is array size, M is number of queries.

But `qsort` implementation is not good enough - it always chooses right element as pivot and for some arrays (already sorted ones or containing repeated elements) gives quadratic sorting time!

If you cannot use sort routine from standard library, just change your implementation - get pivot at random index or use "[median of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Choice_of_pivot)" method

P.S. Also consider replacing of used Lomuto's partition method by Hoare's one (it is not so simple but faster)